# I am transferring a namserver domain what do I need to update?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-registration

Perhaps I am totally over thinking this but I have a domain name and name servers that are working just fine.  I want to transfer the one domain name that I have for my server which is also the name of the nameserver.

e.g.

mydomain.com

with nameservers

ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com

I am transfering the mydomain.com from the current registrar to the one I use for all my other domains.  The question is what do I have to update?  Once the transfer is complete mydomain.com will have ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com as it's nameservers as it is today. I was wondering though how ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com are resolving if mydomain.com is pointing to ns1 and ns2.  Am I over thinking this or am I missing something in the process here?  I always just enter the nameserver names when I configure any domains on my server.  Do I have to setup A records somewhere for ns1 and ns2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key item: Since you are **only** changing your registrar and not the underlying IP addresses associated with your nameservers, this move is transparent.

Be sure to enter glue records (nameserver + IP) at your new registrar. If you are using a primary registrar, I typically see this information show up in the root servers within 5 minutes.

Use a tool like http://www.intodns.com/

To confirm things are working as they should.

If your nameserver IPs are changing, then you have other issues to handle, but for a registrar change with no underlying DNS record changes - it is transparent.

Comment: I think the glue record is the piece I was missing.  I just looked that term up and that glue record now makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to point your servers to another name server I think, because once they move to registrar they would no longer be serving DNS correct? Just dumb records. I think it's probably safer to rename your domain.internal something though and point to internal dns. Depends on how you were serving DNS on the original servers though.

Comment: I have no idea which is why I'm asking the question.  The DNS server is not moving, only the registrar.

Comment: Well depending on if internally you need to hit those externals you still might need to add a DNS record, but you should be good :)

Comment: these are ALL external servers, none are internal.

Answer (score 0):

****EDIT:**  It turns out I'm completely wrong.  See the comments.  I'd delete this, but I imagine other people might think the same thing I did in answering it, so I'll leave it as a cautionary tale.**

That's an interesting exercise in recursion.

If I understand your question correctly:

You want `mydomain.com` to have `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com` as its nameservers?

That will not work.  You can't have a nameserver in the same domainspace as the domain name.

It's a chicken/egg scenario.  When you run a DNS lookup, eventually the nameservers are queried.  If `ns1.mydomain.com` is the nameserver for `mydomain.com`, how do you ever get a lookup for `ns1.mydomain.com`?  That is - something has to tell you what the IP address is for `ns1.mydomain.com` so that you can query it.  If `ns1.mydomain.com` is where you have to go to get the IP address for `ns1.mydomain.com`, how does `ns1.mydomain.com` ever resolve in the first place?

Generally your nameservers need to be in different namespace than the domain they're hosting.

Comment: Circular dependencies are handled through glue records. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records
It is quite common for domain.com and nameservers to share the same domain.

Comment: I learn something new every day.  Thanks for the update.  I would not have thought that'd work.

Comment: +1 for being open enough to admit you were incorrect and leaving it for others to learn from. That's a lesson for all of us.